# Обработка событий клавиатуры jsp servlet

Tags: javascript, java, swing, jsp, servlet

Когда-то писал десктопное приложение на java, где считывались события клавиатуры (когда, какая клавиша была нажата, сколько удерживалась и т.д.) и, после, эти параметры, в процессе аутентификации, сравнивались с эталонными значениями с бд. Сейчас решил перенести это все в web и столкнулся с проблемой, что раньше-то, для обработки событий, использовал swing, а при работе с jsp, на сколько знаю, он не катит, если только апплеты не писать.

Есть ли какие-то средства для динамической обработки событий клавиатуры, при работе с jsp, не прибегая к написанию разных апплетов, может быть с помощью js'овских onkeydown и onkeyup?

Comment: может поможет https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

Comment: именно оно, сижу разбираюсь, спасибо

Comment: не за что .....